# transitioning to use redux with hooks

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks

figuring out how to use redux with hooks using this way but not sure its the correct way

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { getPins } from "../../../actions/pins";

function MainStory() {
  const pins = useSelector(state => state.pins.pins);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getPins(pins));
  }, []);
  console.log(pins);
return(<div> test </div>
```

would the above way be the right way to go despite missing dependencies?

> React Hook useEffect has missing dependencies: 'dispatch' and 'pins'. Either include them or remove the dependency array

with components (the way i had it before)

```
import { getPins } from "../../actions/pins";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
export class Pins extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    pins: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
    getPins: PropTypes.func.isRequired
  };
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getPins();
  }
  render() {
    console.log(this.props.pins);
    return <div>test</div>;
  }
}
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  pins: state.pins.pins
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { getPins })(Pins);
```

the plan is to list each pin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add `dispatch` to the dependencies list, since it won't change. If you'll add the `pins` to dependancies list of the `useEffect` block, you might cause infinite loop, if the response to the action changes the state (call to server that returns an array).

However, according to the class component example, the `getPins()` action creator doesn't require the value of `pins`, so you can just add `dispatch` to the list of dependancies:

```
function MainStory() {
  const pins = useSelector(state => state.pins.pins);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getPins());
  }, [dispatch]);
  console.log(pins);
return(<div> test </div>
```

Comment: ah so i didnt need to put pins in getPins(pins)

Comment: Should `dispatch` always be added as a dependency? I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around this.

Comment: @FredrikNorlin - Everything that is used inside a hook and might change should be added to dependencies. The dispatch won't actually change, so you can skip it. However, the eslint hooks plugin will warn you (`react-hooks/exhaustive-deps` rule), because it doesn't know that dispatch won't change, so you'll probably include it anyway.